# Анимация появления фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment, анимация, android-animation

Я хочу анимировать появление фрагмента. При чем чтобы он появлялся "сверху вниз".  Мне частично удалось реализовать задумку, но проблема в том что сначала появляется место на экране под фрагмент, а только потом появляется сам фрагмент с анимацией. Как сделать одновременную анимацию появления места на экране и анимацию появления фрагмента?

Вот что имею:

[image: Гифка с анимацией]

---

Экран разметки

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="simpleproject.diary.MainScreenTableView">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/two_lines_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </FrameLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/recyclerview_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Методы, запускающие анимацию

```
private void calendarShow() {
    FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.calendar_show, R.animator.calendar_hide);
    t.replace(R.id.calendarView, mCalendar, CALENDAR_TAG);
    t.show(mCalendar);
    t.commit();
    mCalendar.refreshView();
}

private void calendarHide() {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.calendar_show, R.animator.calendar_hide);
    t.hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CALENDAR_TAG));
    t.commit();
}
```

Анимации появления и исчезновения

calendar_show.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="300"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="y"
        android:valueFrom="-1000"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

calendar_hide.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="300"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="y"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="-1000"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Comment: Евгений, а ты хочешь это сделать в виде падающего окна (popup) или тебе необходимо смещать список чтобы появлялся фрагмент ?

Comment: @KolinLoures я бы хотел смещать список

Comment: А дефолтные анимации из animateLayoutChanges вас не устраивают?

Comment: @RealKEK я пробовал метод setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN) и setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK) но они никак не влияли на анимацию.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить AnimationListener для управления видимостью фрагмента:

```
private void calendarShow() {
FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.calendar_show);

anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
     @Override
     public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
     }
     @Override
     public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
     }
     @Override
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
     //Сделайте фрагмент видимым - setVisibility(VISIBLE);
     }
 });

t.startAnimation(anim);
t.replace(R.id.calendarView, mCalendar, CALENDAR_TAG);
t.show(mCalendar);
t.commit();

//Сделайте фрагмент невидимым - setVisibility(GONE);
mCalendar.refreshView();
}
```